# Android SoundPool Cannot Play Through Single Channel

Tags: android, audio, xamarin, wav

We're playing a wav file through Android's SoundPool API. We've created a device that loops one of the stereo channels back through the microphone, but not the other.

I should also mention that we've tested our loopback device with a computer and have confirmed it works correctly.

However, when we try to play a sound through the channel that is not looped back to the microphone, we're still "hearing" the sound from that channel on the microphone. When we plug headphones in, it seems Android is still sending a quieter version of the one-channel sound through to the other channel even when it's not supposed to.

We've tried stereo WAV files with silence on one channel and we've tried mono sound files -- both are played the same. Can anyone explain this and how to stop it? The code we're using is:

```
_Pool = new SoundPool(3, Stream.Music, 0);
var beep = assets.OpenFd("beep.wav");
var beepId = _Pool.Load(beep, 1);

//later, after the sound is loaded we call:
_Pool.Play(beepId, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1);
```

I should also mention that we've tried variations of the volume levels (0.01 instead of 0.0 and 0.99 instead of 1.0). We've also tried it on multiple test devices including a Google Pixel, Samsung Note, and an LG. Nothing seems to work. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "feature" is inherent in all the `Android.Media.*` package media output and it happens on physical and emulated devices due to the Android audio stack due to the fact Android supports up to 8 channel audio and *mixes* all available channels to produce the audio output.

i.e. If you create an AudioFormat that masks out all channels except the right channel, you will still have some output on the left channel (assuming you are using a 2-channel output device) regardless of the `AudioAttributes`:

```
var audioFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .SetChannelIndexMask(2) // Right channel
                .SetSampleRate(8000)
                .SetEncoding(Encoding.Pcm16bit)
                .Build();
```

These APIs are above the `AudioFlinger`, `libmedia`, the `HAL`, etc... and thus are subject to the final mixing provide by the FastMixer/NormalMixer/AudioMixer, etc...

You can look ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture) and OSS (Open Sound System) in order to access the hardware audio services in order to bypass the normal audio handling.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We ended up "fixing" this with a modification to our hardware.